# Replace a module in an Excel file: Document not saved error

Tags: excel, vba

The code is used to update several worksheets in different locations. It will update a particular module that I will specify.

This code was working last week.

Now it will throw an error saving the workbook.

> run-time error '1004' Document not saved"

I am guessing because Excel updates itself and there were some changes in the updates.

The Excel version I am using is Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2209 Build 16.0.15629.20200) 64-bit.

How could I replace a module in an Excel file given the source is in a text file as .bas extension?

```vb
Sub Update_VBA_Module_Pricing_Tool()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim wbUpdate As Workbook
    Dim ModuleFile As String

    Set wsActive = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Pricing")
    
    'Loop Thru Files Listed in Col A
    i = 2
    While wsActive.Range("A" & i).Value <> ""
        If wsActive.Range("C" & i).Value = "Y" Then
            Application.StatusBar = "Updating " & wsActive.Range("B" & i).Value & " ..."
            
            'DirFile = Workbooks.Open(wsActive.Range("A" & i).Value)
            If IsFile(wsActive.Range("A" & i).Value) = False Then
                MsgBox wsActive.Range("B" & i).Value & " does not exist..."
                GoTo proceed_to_next:
            End If
        
            'Dim wbTemp As Workbook
            'Set wbTemp = Workbooks.Open("D:\Spark RE Analytics, LLC\Spark Vault - General\02-Pricing Properties\Tuesday-pm-G-BLD\1. Pricing Tool\Week 111 22-10-23\1_BLD Portfolio Pricing Tool Week 111.xlsm")
                    
            Set wbUpdate = Workbooks.Open(wsActive.Range("A" & i).Value)
            Set vbp = Workbooks(wbUpdate.Name).VBProject
        
            'Loop Thru VBA Modules in Col D
            j = 2
            While wsActive.Range("H" & j).Value <> ""
                If wsActive.Range("J" & j).Value = "Y" Then
                    'Set module to Process
                    ModuleFile = wsActive.Range("H" & j).Value
                    modulename = wsActive.Range("I" & j).Value
            
                    'Replace Module in Workbook
                    Set vbp = Workbooks(wbUpdate.Name).VBProject
            
                    With vbp.VBComponents
                        .Remove vbp.VBComponents(modulename)
                        '.Import ModuleFile
                        Set temp = .Import(ModuleFile)
                        temp.Name = modulename
                    End With
                    ' end of insert other things to file
                End If
                
                j = j + 1
            Wend
    
            'Save File
            wbUpdate.Save
            wbUpdate.Close False
            Application.StatusBar = "Finished Updating " & wsActive.Range("B" & i).Value & " ..."
        End If

proceed_to_next:
        i = i + 1
    Wend

apps_exit:
    MsgBox "Done!"
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you write permission to the file? Is the file blocked from a outer application? Can you open and save the file manual?

Comment: When I open the file manually using Excel, I am able to edit and save the file.  When I use code to update the file like changing a value of a cell, it saves without problem.  It only gives the error when I update a module in the file which works before but just this week doesn't work anymore.  I also tried different computer, same result.

Comment: Is it for all modules or only a specific one? Can you compiler the workbook after injecting the code?

Comment: Can you manually save the file after the module has been updated by code?

Comment: It is only updating only one specific module in the worksheet.  After vba has injected the code, it throws an error of document not saved at the .save line.  When I try to save the file manually after the code injected the module, I also cannot save the file.  Sometimes it throws document not saved, sometimes it says errors detected while saving excel file.  Seems the file is corrupted.  But when I do not use VBA, I go to the same file and update module manually, it saves without a problem.

Comment: Perhaps you should clean the project thoroughly: 1. Export all modules, including the Sheet and TWB modules. 2. Save-as the file to xlsx. 3. Close Excel. 4. Open the newly saved xlsx 5. Import all exported modules (you'll have to manually copy and paste the code from the object files). 6. Save-as to xlsm

Comment: If anyone can share sample working code that updates a single module to a target workbook from a source textfile (.bas).  Note that this source code was just working last week and it stop working for this week.  If anybody can share a code that updates module programatically that still works tried and tested today, I will be very thankful.